# Kazhdan Property T of semisimple Lie groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, unitary-representations, property-t

I am reading the paper [Margulis, G. A.; Nevo, A.; Stein, E. M., 
*[Analogs of Wiener's ergodic theorems for semisimple Lie groups. II.](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1092749435)*
Duke Math. J. 103 (2000), no. 2, 233–259] ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1760627)).

I want to understand the following argument.
Let $(G,K)$ be a Gelfand pair. Then $M(G,K)$ i.e. the set of all bi-$K$-invariant measures on $G$ is a commutative Banach algebra. Suppose $\tau:G\to B(\mathcal H_\tau)$ be a strongly continuous unitary representation of $G.$ Denote $A_{\tau}:=\overline{\tau(M(G,K)}.$ Then spectrum of $A_\tau$ can be identified with all positive definite spherical functions on $G.$ How do you see that?

Secondly given a probability measure $\mu\in M(G,K)$ define $$\|\mu\|_T:=\sup\{|\phi_\lambda(\mu)|:\text{$\phi_\lambda$ positive-definite spherical function}\}.$$ Then $\|\mu\|_T\geq \tau(\mu).$

I do not understand the identification of spectrum of $A_\tau$ with positive-definite spherical functions. Secondly, what does one mean by $\phi_\lambda(\mu)$ since $\phi_\lambda$ is supposed to be a function on $G$?

Comment: Did you check the four references given for the identification?

Comment: Also, $\phi_\lambda(\mu)$ means that $\phi_\lambda$ is viewed as a character of $\overline{\tau(M(G, K))}$, then evaluated at $\tau(\mu)$.

Comment: Anyway, (1) notice that the spectrum is not identified with *all* pdsf's, but only a subset, and (2) I think that the identification is the simple one:  given a character $\chi$ of $\overline{\tau(M(G, K))}$, send $g \in G$ to the value of $\chi \circ \tau$ at the unit mass on $K g K$.

Comment: @LSpice. I understand that given a character $\chi$ of $A_\tau$ I can define a character a character on $G$ as $i(\chi)g\mapsto \tau(m_K*\delta_g*m_k).$ But I think what I need to show that the map $\chi\mapsto  i(\chi)$ is injective and continuous in some topology to obtain the spectral theorem. Am I right? Even after the identification you mentioned there are some subtlities. I checked the references. In the book of Gangoli something like that is given but for $L^1(G,K)$.

Comment: The closed span of the various unit $K g K$'s is $M(G, K)$, so injectivity follows.  (Also, you can delete [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358123/kazhdan-property-t-of-semisimple-lie-groups#comment900675_358123).)

Comment: Ok. I agree. But here $G$ has to be $\sigma$-compact for that. Right? Since we know that probability measures on a compact Hausdroff space is closed convex hull of Dirac masses. Hence you can take a measure, make it compactly supported, normalized, approximate by convex combinations of Dirac masses and the make the compact sets large so that it covers $G$ asymptotically.

Comment: $G$ is a (finite-dimensional) Lie group, so it is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107002/discussion-between-a-beginner-mathmatician-and-lspice).

Comment: @LSpice. I have understand the identification clearly. But in my question (and also in the paper I mentioned in the question, "$\phi_\lambda(\mu)$" can be defined only for the spherical positive-definite functions $i(\chi)$ (this notation appears in my previous posts.) In this case $\|\mu\|_T=\tau(\mu)$ because the Gelfand transform is an isometry. So how to use your "subset" argument to show $\|\mu\|_T\geq \tau(\mu)$?